# Formatting output aligned automatically

Tags: printing

```
pars = {f0, p, mu, sigma, alpha, beta};
numpars = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], 0.01];
numparsse = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], 0.01];
Table[
     Print[pars[[i]]
     , " = "
     , numpars[[i]]
     , "( "
     , numparsse[[i]]
     , ")"]
     , {i, 1, Length[pars]}
]
```

This gives pretty much what I want, but I want to do more, like this

```
   f0 = 0.95 ( 0.16 )
    p = 0.33 ( 0.2  )
   mu = 0.04 ( 0.2  )
sigma = 0.29 ( 0.64 )
alpha = 0.13 ( 0.37 )
 beta = 0.48 ( 0.54 )
```

More or less aligned, nicely spaced out.
I am sure that `Table` is not the proper way to do this. But this is what I can come up with at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Grid` and the `Alignment` option:

```
dt = {#1, "=", #2, "(", #3, ")"} & @@@ Transpose[{pars, numpars, numparsse}];

Grid [dt, Alignment -> {Right, Center}]
```

[image]